# Why do I get an incorrect result when trying to convert from Hex to Dec in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion

**Solved**

My function isn't working properly. When I do hex2dec "100" or "10000" it gives me 16 instead of the correct 256. When I do hex2dec "101" it gives me 17 instead of the correct 257.

```
hex2dec :: String -> Integer
hex2dec str = go (reverse str)
      where go []     = 0
            go (x:xs) = hexChar x + 16 * hex2dec xs

hexChar :: Char -> Integer
hexChar c
      | c == '0' = 0
      | c == '1' = 1
      | c == '2' = 2
      | c == '3' = 3
      | c == '4' = 4
      | c == '5' = 5
      | c == '6' = 6
      | c == '7' = 7
      | c == '8' = 8
      | c == '9' = 9
      | c == 'a' = 10
      | c == 'b' = 11
      | c == 'c' = 12
      | c == 'd' = 13
      | c == 'e' = 14
      | c == 'f' = 15
      | otherwise     = 0
```

Comment: Tips: take a look at `Data.List.findIndex` for a nicer way to write `hexChar`. If this is not an exercise there's also `Numeric.readHex`.

Comment: Thanks. Yea, this isn't an exercise. Just a codeeval challenge.

Comment: ... aren't those exercises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change "hex2dec" to "go".

```
hex2dec :: String -> Integer
hex2dec str = go (reverse str)
      where go []     = 0
            go (x:xs) = hexChar x + 16 * go xs
```

Comment: To avoid the call to `reverse`, try writing it using tail recursion using an accumulator - e.g. http://www.siddharta.me/2006/04/recursion-part-2-tail-recursion.html

Comment: @ErikR got it. Thanks for the idea.
     hex2dec acc [] = acc
     hex2dec acc (x:xs) = hex2dec (acc * 16 + hexChar x) xs

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your functions are partial; not all `Char` values are valid hex digits. Instead, define a new type to represent them:

```
data Hex = H0 | H1 | H2 | H3
         | H4 | H5 | H6 | H7
         | H8 | H9 | HA | HB
         | HC | HD | HE | HF deriving (Enum)
```

Deriving an `Enum` instance gives you `hexChar` (let's call it `hexInt`) for nearly for free; we switch from `Int` to `Integer` here.

```
hexInt :: Hex -> Integer
hexInt = fromIntegral . fromEnum
```

With this in place, you can use Horner's Rule to reduce a list of `Hex` values to an `Integer`.

```
hex2dec :: [Hex] -> Integer
hex2dec = foldr (\d acc -> hexInt d + 16*acc) 0
```

---

To generalize this from `[Hex]` to `String`, we first define a function to convert a `Char` to a `Maybe Hex`

```
import Data.List

charToHex :: Char -> Maybe Hex
charToHex c = fmap toEnum $ c `elemIndex` "0123456789abcdef"
-- elemIndex returns a Maybe Int "between" Just 0 and Just 15;
-- fmap toEnum converts that to a Maybe Hex.
```

If you wanted to be explicit, `charToHex` is of course simply

```
charToHex '0' = Just H0
-- ...
charToHex 'f' = Just H15
charToHex _ = Nothing
```

Then we want a function that can handle any failures while mapping `charToHex` over a `String`.

```
str2dec :: String -> Maybe Integer
str2dec = fmap hex2dec . traverse charToHex
```

where `traverse charToHex :: String -> Maybe [Hex]` returns `Nothing` if any call to `charToHex` on the input string returns `Nothing`.